# viewDidLoad or didLayoutSubviews for setting rounded corners?

Tags: swift, uikit

i'm looking for the perfect place in my code to set rounded cornerRadius to my views.
Sometimes it seems like the UI shrinks my view after i set the cornerRadius to `frame.height/2` so im getting a "more then round" view (looks like an eye)

I'm building my App with Interface Builder, so I thought `viewDidLoad` should be the right method to call `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height/2`

I also tried to design my views in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but there were also some strange results

So my general question is:
Where should I place my `cornerRadius` code to be sure that I'm getting the right result?

Thanks for your replies!

EDIT:

The problem is especially with buttons (or views) with proportional height to superview. With fixed height its working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you only placed the `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height/2` in viewDidLoad?

If placed it in both views then remove it from subviews.

And make sure that the button is a "Square" in Size. I mean height and weight are equal.

Comment: I tried both: Only in viewDidLoad and only in didLayoutSubviews
Both does not work fine with proportional Heights